# How can the width of a SELECT dropdown be controlled?

Tags: html, css, html-select

I have several dropdowns on the page one under another, and would like to have them all be the same width (for simplicity's sake, assume dropdown 1 has all values 1 character, and dropdown 2 has all values 10 characters, but you don't know "10" in advance when you are printing dropdown 1).

Is there a way to set the dropdown width to some pre-determined max width in pixels?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select { width:200px }
```

(This text brought to you by the 30-character limit.)

Comment: For some reason that wasn't working for me... may have been a typo; so I assumed it was something fancier. I just tried it again and it worked - thanks!